# Clone or Copy UIViewController or UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, copy, clone

UII need copy, self controller or self.view, i have tried:

```
UIView* viewOfSelf =[self.view copy];
UIViewController* controller = [self copy];

UIView* viewOfSelf =[self.view mutableCopy];
UIViewController* controller = [self mutableCopy];
```

The error is:

```
    -[UIViewController mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb803490
    -[UIView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e0acb0
```

Comment: what is the class of `self` ? `MyViewController` ? I think there is no mutable copy of `UIView` and `UIViewController`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use -

```
NSData *tempArchiveView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.view];
UIView *viewOfSelf = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempArchiveView];
```

Similarly -

```
NSData *tempArchiveViewController = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
UIViewController *controller = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempArchiveViewController];
```

Comment: Doesn't get everything such as custom gestures, etc.

Comment: Hmm didn't get my UIImageView I had as a subview of the view I was cloning.

Answer (score 5):

For an object to be copyable it must implement `NSCopying` protocol which `UIView` class nor `UIViewController` class do not.

If you want to copy a view, I'm pretty sure you're doing something wrong. The copying should be replaced by reusable `UIView` just like in `UITableView` using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method.

Copying view controller is definitely an anti-pattern. If you want exact copy of the view controller that you already have - create a new instance of it with same parameters that current one is.

Comment: Eventhough Rishi's answer worked for me as well, but creating new instances proved to be a more reliable solution for my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I am not yet allowed to comment, but rishi's solution has one problem: it does not copy `NSLayoutConstraint`s. So if any of your views are using autolayout, those are not going to get copied. I am writing a mini-lib to solve that and will post it to github when done. Unfortunately, I haven't found a ready-to-use solution anywhere.

//Edit

Sorry, what I wrote previously was not completely correct. I did some more research and it turns out that on default, the `NSLayoutConstraint`s in the archived view are NOT saved. But, you can actually specify if you want to archive a constraint by setting its `shouldBeArchived` property to `YES`. Then, even after this fake `copy`, you retain the right constraints in the copied view.