# Not Enough Cell to Use in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have created a UITableView in Storyboard and it is dynamically cell. The problem is that when there are not enough cells to reuse, it randomly empties a few of my cells. I think this is logical, but I want to resolve this problem.

I give an example:
I have a UITableView that is capable to generate 10 cells in a view. But now, I only want to show 8 cells out of 10. It gives no problem when I have only a section. With more than 1 section, it will always empty 2 cells and show 8 cells, but it should show 10 cells.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

**Updated With Source code**

```
#pragma mark - List View
#pragma mark - Table View Delegate
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section {
   // Number of rows is the number of time zones in the region for the          specified section.
  return self.listCollection.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   for (id object in cell.contentView.subviews) {
       [object removeFromSuperview];
   }

   [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.listCollection   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

   return cell;

}
```

**self.listCollection** has an array of UIView Object.

**Updated With Images:**

1. [Image 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hzzistkd8vtc36/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-26%20at%202.29.52%20PM.png?dl=0)
2. [Image 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1vfwfsxgx546se/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-26%20at%202.30.01%20PM.png?dl=0)

Comment: you "want to show 8 cells out of 10" without scrolling the view?

Comment: No actually. My tableview can show 8 cells without scrolling. What i mean is when there is more than a section, there empty 2 cells, but it suppose to show 10 cells, this cause the bug.

Comment: post the code how you are populating the cells.

Comment: How come you are getting 2 sections when your datasource delegate is returning 1 ?

Comment: Sry for that, just now i want to try something, so i changed back to 1, actually i should post the code with return 2.

Comment: dont know if it is related to the problem.
in these lines
for (id object in cell.contentView.subviews) {
       [object removeFromSuperview];
   }

   [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.listCollection   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

why dont you create a custom cell with those subview in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you are using 2 sections but are not specifying the content for each section separately. To understand this we need to look into the description of `addSubview:` method from [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview:)

> This method establishes a strong reference to view and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.
>
> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, **this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview**.

Have a good look at bold section in second paragraph. As you are using the same view object from `listCollection` to populate both the section, so newest created cell will become the `superview` for this view object and previous cell will be left out with nothing but the plane `contentView`. You can get the real feel by assigning some default color to the cell `contentView`. Your blank cell will be displaying the color in full content while other cells will display the *view*

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

**Solution**
I will recommend to use 2 different datasource for both sections as explained below.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section {
   // Number of rows is the number of time zones in the region for the          specified section.  
   if(section==0)
      return self.listCollection.count; 
   else   
      return <row count for section 1>  
 }
```

Same way you need to modify the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code for each section.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   for (id object in cell.contentView.subviews) {
       [object removeFromSuperview];
   }
   if(section==0)
      [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.listCollection   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   else
      [cell.contentView addSubview:[<second array of views>   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

   return cell;
}
```

But if that is your case that you have to use same array, then you can use this technique. Thanks to [Rishi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614276/clone-or-copy-uiviewcontroller-or-uiview) for that.
Last but not least, you should use a custom `UITableViewCell` class as *Michal Zygar* has suggested in his post.

```
UIView *tempView = [self.listCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSData *tempArchiveView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:tempView];
UIView *viewOfSelf = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempArchiveView];
[cell.contentView addSubview:viewOfSelf];
```

Comment: wow, thats really cool. Thank you very much, it solved the problem. Can you explain how NSData worked?

Comment: `archivedDataWithRootObject` converts the root object i.e. `tempView` to binary data and while unarchiving this data it creates an object from that data. This process maintains the data type of object but will return a fresh object of `UIView`. Check the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000837-SW4) for details.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you very much. Do u know any site that will help iOS Developer to improve their skills?

Comment: @tan- [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) and [Big Nerd](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/) has many beginner's tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the UITableView wrong way.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   for (id object in cell.contentView.subviews) {
       [object removeFromSuperview];
   }

   [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.listCollection   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

   return cell;

}
```

This is highly inapriopriate. Your `listCollection` should contain model data. In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you should configure the cell with this data.

So you should subclass the `UITableViewCell` for example

```
@interface ApartmentCell:UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel* floor;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel* unit;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel* type;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel* area;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel* price;
@end
```

and then

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  ApartmentCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  Apartment* apartment=self.listCollection[indexPath.row];

  cell.unit.text=apartment.unit;
   //and so on with other fields
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Zygar - I agree with your point, but i don't think this is the reason why he is facing the issue.

Comment: Gandalf, I bet there's something wrong with the views in `self.collectionList`. Even if it's not, he's playing against the tableView implementation. I think rewriting code this way would be faster than debugging(plus we are improving code quality). The least he could do is to move `removeFromSuperView` loop to `prepareForReuse`

Comment: Agreed with your point about code quality, but this is not a problem with array but rather how `addSubview` works. Please check my answer below.

Comment: Hi Zygar, I have followed your instruction to create custom cell with subclass UITableViewCell. But when i perform assign i.e. `cell.unit.text=apartment.unit;` the app crashed, and give this error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell label]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9bc274b5e0'`

After i delete that line, the application works fine.